# Sorting a large .txt file alphabetically

Tags: python

I'm having a slight problem with the following Python script.

I am trying to sort a list alphabetically (case sensitive, and numbers may be included). The list is generated from the content read from an input file.

The input file is rather large, at a size of about 219MB. However, after I run the script, the output .txt file is only 1570KB. Can someone help me identify why this is the case?

```
# The built-in function `open` opens a file and returns a file object.

# Read mode opens a file for reading only.
try:
    f = open("dict.txt", "r")
    try:
        # Read the entire contents of a file at once.
        # string = f.read() 
        # OR read one line at a time.
        #line = f.readline()
        # OR read all the lines into a list.
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines.sort()
        f.close()
        f = open('output.txt', 'w')
        f.writelines(lines) # Write a sequence of strings to a file
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

Comment: And if instead of `pass` you try to print exceptions? And please reindent correctly.

Comment: What does the output file contain?

Comment: Your code is broken, you have two `try`'s and only one `except`. Also, is there any output in the console when you run it?

Comment: Tip: you can use the context manager `with open(filename, mode) as f:` to avoid the worry of closing files.

Comment: I guess the whitespace is just messed up, it's one try: finally: and one (outer) try: except:

Comment: i would use os.system(cmd), where cmd is linux command to sort the file (like sed or sort). this would be faster then to read all file,and use line.sort()

Comment: The `pass` in the `IOError` can hide alot. Print the exception instead of passing.

Comment: Any reason you don't do `sort dict.txt > output.txt`?

Comment: @Daniel: I suspect this is homework.

Comment: @Lawrence: They have valid code. `try..finally` is perfectly legal. It is rather old-skool though; there was a time you could use either `try..finally` or `try..except` but not both. That has changed now, but that doesn't make this *invalid*.